# signalr/hubs 404 when running on iis 7.5 but not vs2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

Im using [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) code verbatim

When I run this is VS2013 its fine, when I copy and paste files to C:\inetpub\wwwroot and access via http://localhost it gives me a 404.

Comment: Use chrome developer tools to trace the request and ser what's really hapening. Take a look at event log and iis log too.

Comment: @Oscar I am a newbie at this i'm now sure how to do that exactly.

Comment: See this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en